# Trouble setting state with onClick function only with ImageMapper component (react-img-mapper)

Tags: reactjs, onclick, onclicklistener, react-props

I'm trying to create an interactive image map using the ImageMapper component from [react-img-mapper](https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper) (based on [react-image-mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-mapper)) in my ReactJS app.  I want to be able to click an "area" on ImageMapper map, and have it update `clickedAreas` state according to the function `clickArea`.

In the app, I render a list with checkmarks, and the checkmarks become green when the corresponding list item is included in `clickedAreas` state.

I call `clickArea` via **onClick** on list items themselves and it works as expected, but when I call it via the ImageMapper **onClick prop** it doesn't, and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

---

---

[**Here's a screen recording showing the differences in action.**](https://youtube.com/shorts/SmmGTvqcvoA)

*NOTE:  the ImageMapper onClick seems to be using the initially set state (`useState([])`), because when I give it an array with an element initially, it just keeps using that initial state with that element.*

**Here's a screenshot regarding the onClick prop from react-img-mapper documentation**
[image: Here's a screenshot regarding the onClick prop from react-img-mapper documentation]

---

---

**Here's a screenshot of my code:**
[image: Here's a screenshot of my code.]

---

---

**Here's my code also:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import ImageMapper from 'react-img-mapper';


function ImageMapQQ(props) {

  const URL = "../images/qqmap.png"
  const MAP = {
    name: "qq-map",
    areas: [
      { id: "NW1/4NW1/4", title: "NW1/4NW1/4", name: "NW1/4NW1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [0,0,50,50] },
      { id: "NE1/4NW1/4", title: "NE1/4NW1/4", name: "NE1/4NW1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [50,0,100,50] },
      { id: "NW1/4NE1/4", title: "NW1/4NE1/4", name: "NW1/4NE1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [100,0,150,50] },
      { id: "NE1/4NE1/4", title: "NE1/4NE1/4", name: "NE1/4NE1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [150,0,200,50] },

      { id: "SW1/4NW1/4", title: "SW1/4NW1/4", name: "SW1/4NW1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [0,50,50,100] },
      { id: "SE1/4NW1/4", title: "SE1/4NW1/4", name: "SE1/4NW1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [50,50,100,100] },
      { id: "SW1/4NE1/4", title: "SW1/4NE1/4", name: "SW1/4NE1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [100,50,150,100] },
      { id: "SE1/4NE1/4", title: "SE1/4NE1/4", name: "SE1/4NE1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [150,50,200,100] },

      { id: "NW1/4SW1/4", title: "NW1/4SW1/4", name: "NW1/4SW1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [0,100,50,150] },
      { id: "NE1/4SW1/4", title: "NE1/4SW1/4", name: "NE1/4SW1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [50,100,100,150] },
      { id: "NW1/4SE1/4", title: "NW1/4SE1/4", name: "NW1/4SE1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [100,100,150,150] },
      { id: "NE1/4SE1/4", title: "NE1/4SE1/4", name: "NE1/4SE1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [150,100,200,150] },

      { id: "SW1/4SW1/4", title: "SW1/4SW1/4", name: "SW1/4SW1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [0,150,50,200] },
      { id: "SE1/4SW1/4", title: "SE1/4SW1/4", name: "SE1/4SW1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [50,150,100,200] },
      { id: "SW1/4SE1/4", title: "SW1/4SE1/4", name: "SW1/4SE1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [100,150,150,200] },
      { id: "SE1/4SE1/4", title: "SE1/4SE1/4", name: "SE1/4SE1/4", shape: "rect", coords: [150,150,200,200] },
    ]
  }

  const areas = MAP.areas
  const [clickedAreas, setClickedAreas] = useState([])

  function clickArea(id) {
    console.log("clickedAreas: ", clickedAreas)

    if (clickedAreas.includes(id)) {
      console.log("includes")
      setClickedAreas(() => clickedAreas.filter(el => el != id))
    }
    else {
      console.log("doesn't include")
      setClickedAreas(() => [...clickedAreas, id])
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ImageMapper src={URL} map={MAP}
        stayMultiHighlighted={true}
        toggleHighlighted={true}
        fillColor={"rgba(150, 213, 255, 0.6)"}

        onClick={(area) => clickArea(area.id)} // THIS ONCLICK ISN'T WORKING CORRECTLY
      />

      <div className="bold">AREAS</div>
      {areas.map(area =>
          <>
          <div className="d-flex pointer" onClick={() => clickArea(area.id)}> {/* THIS ONCLICK IS WORKING CORRECTLY */}
            <i className={`fas fa-check-circle ${clickedAreas.includes(area.id) ? "text-green" : "text-black opacity-10"}`}></i>
            <div key={area.id}>{area.id}</div>
          </div>
          </>
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default ImageMapQQ
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it doesn't work as originally written, and would still like more insight on that if anyone's got it.

Ultimately, the ImageMapper onClick just keeps using the initial state (empty array) whenever a click occurs -- I can tell this because I have it console.log the current `clickedAreas` state at the start of the `clickArea` function that's called when the image map is clicked.

It seems to update the state (because the corresponding checkmark turns green), but it seems to always start from the initial state every time the ImageMapper onClick function is called  (console.log shows empty array every time).

**That all being said, I HAVE found a workaround to make it work as desired.**

Instead of the ImageMapper onClick calling the `clickArea` function that later sets state, I changed it to setting a different state immediately (`areaId`), triggering a useEffect that then calls the `clickArea` function that later sets the state I actually wanted to be working with, lol.   Hacky, but works.

(Added the nanoid in there to make it unique upon every click, so that the `setAreaId` function within ImageMapper onClick would always run -- if I just had area.id, it wouldn't run if that area.id was already the `areaId` state.... aka, I couldn't get the `clickArea` function to run to remove it from the `clickedAreas` state)

**The small red circles 1-3 are the new parts of the code:**
[image: The small red circles 1-3 are the new parts of the code]

Comment: After getting this workaround figured out, I also decided to completely switch directions and create an interactive SVG map instead of an interactive HTML map lol.  Way easier to do things and a lot more freedom for styling.